# How to use DMA or RDMA in java?

Tags: java, dma, rdma

"DMA" here means: Direct memory access, and "RDMA" is: remote direct memory access.

I used Java to created an application to transfer stock data, but I found the latency is bigger than I expected. I heard someone developed same type application used "DMA/RDMA", which has good performance, so I wonder if I can use "DMA/RDMA" in Java?

If not, what language should I use, and if there are any good libraries to use?

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-zerocopy/) article from IBM developers work give a great overview of how DMA access can be achieved using java

Comment: The article shows how to allow other parts of the OS to do DMA on Java-created data and achieve zero-copy data transfers. (Cool, if you ask me.)

Comment: @LordDoskias, thank you, zerocopy is a good advice, I will try it later

Comment: Well in order to achieve DMA access of any kind you HAVE to rely on the underlying OS. So each JVM version has platform-specific code which exposes this capability through means of filechannels. So in a sense you are getting all the goodies that come from using DMA

Answer (score 3):

You have two options (that I know of):

1. Java SDP -- has been deprecated
2. JXIO [1], a high-performance messaging library built on RDMA and supported by Mellanox

[1] https://github.com/accelio/JXIO

Comment: Also JSOR from IBM: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.71.doc/diag/understanding/rdma_jsor.html

Answer (score 2):

There is [DiSNI](https://github.com/zrlio/disni), a new library to program RDMA in Java. DiSNI is the open source variant of IBM's jVerbs. There are some performance numbers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098306/java-sockets-on-rdma-jsor-vs-jverbs-performance-in-infiniband) that illustrate how RDMA with Java compares to sockets in C and Java, and also to RDMA in C.

Answer (score 1):

RDMA as I know it is a property of the networking infrastructure (along with the relevant kernel modules etc), not of the application-level programming language.

In other words, you'd have to get specialized kit to make use of RDMA to reduce network latency. Here is an example of a 10GbE network card that supports RDMA: [link](http://www.mellanox.com/content/pages.php?pg=products_dyn&product_family=63&menu_section=28).

Answer (score 0):

Java applications are capable of mmaping files via nio packages. Those mmaped files can be accesses by multiple programs -  I affraid this is closes thing to DMA available in java

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 supports SDP protocol on Solaris and Linux (with OpenFabrics.org drivers). Unfortunately SDP protocol has been deprecated in the 2.x version of OFED. People resort to JNI wrappers like jVerbs.