# Equivalent of IBM's JVerb in Oracle for RDMA in Java

Tags: java, ethernet, rdma

What is the equivalent of IBM's [JVerb](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/rdma_jverbs.html) in Oracle, if I want to employ RoCE protocol for RDMA over Ethernet?

Edit: Perhaps, JXIO is my best option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [DiSNI](https://github.com/zrlio/disni), a new RDMA library for Java that works with Oracle as well as RoCE. Actually, DiSNI is the open source variant of IBM's JVerbs.

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098306/java-sockets-on-rdma-jsor-vs-jverbs-performance-in-infiniband/38834125#38834125) to get a feeling about the performance you can expect

Answer (score 1):

JVerbs seem work not only with IBM JDK but also with openjdk. It might work with Oracle JDK as well, you just need to copy JAR and native library.